# how to send an array in POST request rest assured

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured

looking for a way to send an array in a post request, its working  on postman, but i cant do the same with rest assured library in java [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hABGD.png)
i tried to create a Map<String,Object> variable and to send it but it also didnt work

how can you send an array with rest assured?

adding a part of the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmcju.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvnr7.png)

up until now i nested JSONobject one into another to send a request and it did work until i had to send an array for the data/steps/data parameter

Comment: Please remove the link to a screenshot of your data, and use the correct tool in the editor to insert code. If necessary, click on the "?" icon in the upper right corner of the editor and read the advanced help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please, add your code that didn't work.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 i added, please tell me if anything else is needed because the answer below didnt work out also for me

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two main approaches. Sending it as string or serializing it from DTO/POJO to json string using library like Gson.
If you want to send the raw string you have to escape the quotes in the json like:

```
static String json = "{\"id\": 110, \"product\": \"Beer\",\"price\": 1900}";
```

If you want to use the DTO/POJO approach you have to create object like this:

```
public class Product {
    public Product(Integer id, String product, Double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
        this.price = price;
    }

    private Integer id;
    private String product;
    private Double price;
}
```

Full example:

```
public class Test {
    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    static String json = "{\"id\": 110, \"product\": \"Beer\",\"price\": 1900}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Setting default rest assured url/base path
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://google.com";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/v1";

        //With escaped string
        RestAssured.given()
                .log().all()
                .body(json).when().post("endpoint");

        //Creating dto
        Product beer = new Product(121212, "Beer", 10.50);
        RestAssured.given()
                .log().all()
                .body(gson.toJson(beer)).when().post("endpoint");

    }


}
```

Console output:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://google.com/v1/endpoint
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{"id": 110, "product": "Beer","price": 1900}



Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://google.com/v1/endpoint
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
  "id": 121212,
  "product": "Beer",
  "price": 10.5
}
```

Content type should match the payload like:

```
   RestAssured.given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log().all()
                .body(gson.toJson(beer)).when().post("endpoint");
```

You can use List or List for the array in the DTO.